# Is it possible to have some LastPass sites stored locally when using Firefox?

Tags: firefox, lastpass

I use LastPass on my laptop, and I often use my laptop at mobile wifi hotspots.

Lastpass won't autofill the form to connect to the wifi network because, until the wifi network is connected, Lastpass can't log in.

What I'd like to do is have LastPass (or Firefox) store the login information for a couple of pages, mainly the two wifi hotspots I use most, so that I can login to those networks automatically.

I know that Firefox can store login information, but it seems that LastPass has taken all control of form fields, so I'm not sure if control can be given back to Firefox on a site by site basis.

Is this possible?

Comment: If LastPass can't connect, it should fall back to offline mode. Is that not happening?

Comment: @AlE., Thank you for responding. I guess it isn't falling back to offline mode. I've just now looked in the settings, though, and I don't see anything about an "offline mode". Can you explain more about what you are referring to?

Comment: If I fire up my browser without a network connection, I can still log in to LastPass, but it warns me that I'm in "offline mode".

Comment: I see the same thing as described in the original question, and it only occurs when you're trying to login to a hotspot - I think the hotspot provides a DNS redirect to its own login page.  Anything else (like LastPass attempting to login) reaching out will be redirected to the same login page.  I'm guessing this "I'm not online but I'm not offline" state is enough to prevent offline mode from activating.